How can I set a column border color based on the date stored in a row?
I'm making a schedule in Google Sheets to keep track of my class assignments:

I want to write a script in the script editor based on the following logic:
for(Column A-Z){
    if(A2,B2,etc = TODAY()){
        Set the border of column A, B, etc to be a green outline
    }else{
        Set an empty border
    }
}

So that it looks like this:

So it needs to automatically outline the column that represents the current day. But I don't really get how to use the Google Sheets API, so I'm at a loss for how to actually make this code work.

Google Sheets built-in functions are not supported by Google Apps Script which is a  cloud-based JavaScript platform.
For example in Apps Script you wouldn't use the TODAY function from Sheets but instead you could achieve the same thing by creating a Javascript date object.
For example, the following script shows how the equivalent is done in Apps Script:
/**
 * Returns a date object with the time set to 12:00:00 AM which is the same
 * as Google Sheets TODA() built-in function.
 */
function todaysDate(){
  return new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
}

Then to set the border use

setBorder(top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal)
setBorder(top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal, color, style)

For details, including code examples, please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range
Related

Add border to whole row if cell in column D is not empty

