# How do I correct the automatic borders that are scripted into this Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, microsoft-excel

I have [this Google Sheet document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_42DyuIR4Cg37STHjtUXR4xGCQ0xh-opfdgTA9L6NwY/edit?usp=sharing) that already has functionality built in which applies automatic borders. I don't know how it is doing this. I've tried looking in the Script Editor, but I don't see any existing scripting in the Script Editor. Perhaps I'm missing something.

I would like to adjust the way it auto-applies borders. Currently, if you insert text in a cell in the "Cue Title" column, it applies a border to two cells down, through Column R. I'd like it to instead apply a top-border to the cell with text in it, through Column R.

There is other auto-functionality built into that document which I'd like to preserve, as well, so I'd like to correct the Google Sheet itself, rather than starting all over from scratch.

How do I adjust this functionality?

Comment: Are you able to identify the conditional formatting rules that are applying the borders in the Google Sheets conditional formatting tool?

Comment: Yes, and this has brought me to a solution to my first post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I already said [in my answer to your previous question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/158676/88163), Google Sheets and the Google Sheets API hasn't a way to change the conditional formatting rules inherited from the Excel file that was converted into a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

One thing that you could try, first clear the conditional formatting rules that are applying the borders, then instead of using the conditional formatting built-in feature use an on edit or on change trigger to set the cell borders by using Google Apps Script.

Related

- [Conditionally format row borders](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110793/88163)
- [Add border to whole row if cell in column D is not empty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/119418/88163)
- [How to give a column a green border if the second row's holds a date = TODAY()?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/133465/88163)